# Trying to insert extracted file names into a single file

Tags: go

This program takes directory name and read all the file inside of the directory after this I am collecting the name of the files and trying to insert the all file names into a new file but I am getting only last index, I want to store all the file names into a single file.

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "regexp"
)

func readCurrentDir(folderpath string) {
    file, err := os.Open(folderpath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("failed opening directory: ", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    list, _ := file.Readdirnames(0) // 0 to read all files and folders
    for _, name := range list {
        getDomainFromFile(name)
    }
}

func CreateDomainsFile(domains string) {
    filename, err := os.Create("All-Sitemap-Domains.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error to create txt file", err)
    }
    defer filename.Close()
    writestrings, err := filename.WriteString(domains)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error to append data into txt file", err)
    }
    log.Println("Successfully data insetred into txt file")
    fmt.Printf("wrote %d bytes\n", writestrings)
    filename.Sync()
}

func getDomainFromFile(PageContent string) {
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`(.*)-robots.txt`)
    // re := regexp.MustCompile(`Sitemap: (.*)`)
    FileToDomain := re.FindAllStringSubmatch(PageContent, -1)
    for _, Domain := range FileToDomain {
        log.Println(Domain[1])
        // log.Println(Domain[1])
        fmt.Println("*************************************************************")
        CreateDomainsFile(string(Domain[1]))
        return
    }

}
func main() {
    folder := flag.String("f", "", "Provide the path of the folder")
    flag.Parse()
    readCurrentDir(*folder)

}
```

Comment: ["Create creates or truncates the named file. If the file already exists, it is truncated."](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Create)

Comment: Would your `os.Create` not wipe down your file every time your `CreateDomainsFile()` func is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first instance you can read all the file into an array:

```golang
// ListFile is delegated to find the files from the given directory, recursively for each dir
func ListFile(path string) []string {
    fileList := []string{}
    // Read all the file recursively
    err := filepath.Walk(path, func(file string, f os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if IsFile(file) {
            fileList = append(fileList, file)
        }
        return nil
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return nil
    }
    return fileList
}
```

Than you can write the file line by line:

```golang
func writeFile(data []string){
    f, err := os.OpenFile("All-Sitemap-Domains.txt", os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error to create txt file", err)
        return
    }
    defer f.Close()
    for i := range data{
       f.WriteString(data[i]+"\n")        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were creating the file again and again so that's the reason you're getting only last value use this if you want to insert values

**filename, os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644**

```
import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "regexp"
)

func readCurrentDir(folderpath string) {
    file, err := os.Open(folderpath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("failed opening directory: ", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    list, _ := file.Readdirnames(0) // 0 to read all files and folders
    for _, name := range list {
        getDomainFromFile(name)
    }
}


func CreateDomainsFile(domains string) {
    filename, err := os.OpenFile("All-Sitemap-Domains.txt", os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error to create txt file", err)
    }
    defer filename.Close()
    writestrings, err := filename.WriteString(domains + "\n")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error to append data into txt file", err)
    }
    log.Println("Successfully data insetred into txt file")
    fmt.Printf("wrote %d bytes\n", writestrings)
    filename.Sync()
}

func getDomainFromFile(PageContent string) {
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`(.*)-robots.txt`)
    FileToDomain := re.FindAllStringSubmatch(PageContent, -1)
    for _, Domain := range FileToDomain {
        log.Println(Domain[1])
        fmt.Println("*************************************************************")
        CreateDomainsFile(string(Domain[1]))
        return
    }

}
func main() {
    // http.HandleFunc("/", index_handler)
    // http.HandleFunc("/sitemap_Domains/", showData)
    // fmt.Println("Development Server Started localhost:8081")
    // http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil)

    folder := flag.String("f", "", "Provide the path of the folder")
    flag.Parse()
    readCurrentDir(*folder)

}
```